# playing intro movie on ipad

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4, mpmovieplayercontroller

i am trying to play an intro movie (like a splash screen). it used to work fine for sdk 3.0 but now i am doing it for iPad. and  its not running movie instead it just show black screen before view appears.
here is my code

```
(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {  
NSString *moviePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"intro" ofType:@"m4v" inDirectory:nil];
NSURL *movieURL = [[NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath] retain];
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
moviePlayer.fullscreen=YES;
moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,1024,768);
[moviePlayer setShouldAutoplay:YES];
[moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];
[moviePlayer setRepeatMode:MPMovieRepeatModeNone];

[moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
[moviePlayer play];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlaybackDidFinish:) 
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                                           object:moviePlayer]; 
return YES;
}
```

and here is my moviePlaybackDidFinish

```
- (void) moviePlaybackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification
{

MPMoviePlayerController *theMovie = [notification object];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                              object:theMovie];
theMovie.initialPlaybackTime = -1;
[theMovie pause]; 

[theMovie stop];
[theMovie release];
[window addSubview:viewController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];


 }
```

i dont know what i am missing here?
thanks for any help....
**UPDATE** i just found out that it plays sound but no video....is this obvious?pls help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're using `MPMoviePlayerController` over `MPMoviePlayerViewController` I think you need to be adding the player's view to your view hierarchy before calling play, as per the docs:

```
[player.view setFrame: myView.bounds];  // player's frame must match parent's
[myView addSubview: player.view]; //add the player' view
```

this might explain why you're hearing audio but not seeing anything, pretty sure you need to setup the app window first too (`[window makeKeyAndVisible];` etc)